# oracle apex master/detail relationship based on a calculated value?

Tags: oracle-apex, master-detail

In `Oracle Apex 5.1`, I'd like to create a `master/detail` form where the relationship is based on a calculated value.  For example the master value is `'ABC_123'` and the detail value is like '`\\aaaa\bbbb\ABC_123_03-MAR-2017.txt`'.  For master value '`ABC_123`', I want to return all the detail records containing '`ABC_123`'.  I can't change the database tables because this is vendor software.  Is there any way to do this in `Apex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to re-design master-detail relationship. Here's how: as you already have an appropriate column in the master table, there's nothing to be done. Suppose that its source query looks like this:

```
select id, name, master_value
from master_table
```

For the detail form, whose query looks like this:

```
select some_date, some_name,
  old_relationship_column      --> this is used to currently create relationship
  detail_value                 --> it is \\aaaa\bbbb\ABC_123_03-MAR-2017.txt
from detail_table
```

you'll have to find a way to extract value which will then be joined with the master form. For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '\\aaaa\bbbb\ABC_123_03-MAR-2017.txt' from dual)
  3  select
  4    substr(col,
  5           instr(col, '\', 1, 4) + 1,
  6           instr(col, '-') - instr(col, '\', 1, 4) - 4) new_rel_col
  7  from test;

NEW_REL
-------
ABC_123
```

Detail query would then be

```
select some_date, some_name,
  old_relationship_column,      --> irrelevant in new design
  detail_value,                 --> it is \\aaaa\bbbb\ABC_123_03-MAR-2017.txt
  --
  substr(detail_value, 
     instr(detail_value, '\', 1, 4) + 1, 
     instr(detail_value, '-') - instr(detail_value, '\', 1, 4) - 4) 
     new_relationship_column             --> oh yes, we'll use it!
from detail_table
```

Now, go to detail form's OLD_RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN properties and remove value from its **Master Column** property.

Next, go to NEW_RELATIONSHIP_COLUMN properties and **set** its Master Column property to master form's MASTER_VALUE column.

That's it - run the form and - if everything is correctly set - you'll have a new relationship alive & kicking. How do I know? Just tested it.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a try

Comment: This worked great.  Since I was adding an interactive grid to an existing page, I had to additionally specify the 'master region' before Apex would allow me to set the Master Column value.  Thanks for your help!